# How to deliver a node.js + imagemagick tool?

Tags: node.js, deployment, imagemagick

I've developed a node.js tool which uses imagemagick from the command line. That is, `exec('my_imagemagick_commands')`. What's the best way to deliver that tool to a client using Windows? That is, how can I make a Windows installer that'll install node.js, imagemagick and the tool - preferably as a binary, not the source - in a specific folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an easy bundle... Zip the list below, deploy on client and drag/drop images to be processed onto the yourtool.cmd file (I'm doing something similar for image optimizers)

Bundle: (put these in one directory)

- yourtool.cmd
- yourtool.js
- node.exe
- node_modules/ (if applicable)

---

**yourtool.cmd**

```
REM Get the drive/path the batch file is in
set batchdir=%~d0%~p0

REM Run tool for items dragged over...
"%batchdir%node.exe" "%batchdir%yourtool.js" %*
```

---

**yourtool.js**

```
// start at 2 for arguments passed...
// 0 is node.exe
// 1 is the js file run
for (var i=2; i<process.argv.length; i++) {
    var imagePath = process.argv[i];
    //do something with image...
}
```

---

For others interested in imagemagick with node, you should check out [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick)

Comment: Not a big deal with the source, just cosmetics really, my problem is having my client to install it. It should be as easy as possible. It's a converter tool, I was thinking I could just tell him "place this file on the folder with the stuff you want to convert and open it - voila". That would be perfect.
Anyway now you're making it hard for ME. How the heck I'm supposed to do what you said on the first paragraph? But well I'll try to figure out.

Comment: @Dokkat sorry, I thought you were wanting to hide your code... I've included an updated answer... zip the list of files above with a .cmd to run node.exe and the script, passing in items dragged/dropped onto the .cmd file.

Comment: What are you excusing at, it was a great answer nevertless. Thanks !